# Why isn't my "menu" displaying properly?

Tags: list, drop-down-menu, menu, show

I used a layout similar to a menu how it has the main menu and a submenu that appears when you hover over it. In this case, I'm trying to have a "Share" menu with the icons the submenu on the same line. I picked details from http://cssdeck.com/labs/another-simple-css3-dropdown-menu Why isn't my menu hiding/showing properly?

HTML

```css
a {
  padding: 4px;
}
i.fa {
  color: #8b8b8b;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
ul li ul {
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
ul li ul:hover {
  display: block;
}
ul li ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="color: #676767;"> <a style="color: #676767;" href="#"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i> Share</a>
    <ul class="socialShare">
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://test.gpjbaker.com/brands/gp-j-baker/denbury-collection/"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://twitter.com/home?status=http://test.gpjbaker.com/brands/gp-j-baker/denbury-collection/"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://test.gpjbaker.com/brands/gp-j-baker/denbury-collection/&media=&description="><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code on a separated file, and i detected that your mistake was in the html. I supposed that you want to create on hover effect on the Share, and then show the social networks.. Here's the code of the HTML properly coded.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a style="color: #676767;" href="#"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i> Share</a>
        <ul class="socialShare">
            <li>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://test.gpjbaker.com/brands/gp-j-baker/denbury-collection/"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>Facebook</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/home?status=http://test.gpjbaker.com/brands/gp-j-baker/denbury-collection/"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>Twitter</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://test.gpjbaker.com/brands/gp-j-baker/denbury-collection/&media=&description="><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i>Pinterest</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the menu isn't appearing is because the menu `<ul>` which you are trying to show has `visibility: hidden`, and that property is not being changed on `hover`. Since that element already has `display: none` set (which does get set to `block` on `hover`), you can remove the `visibility` property.

I see that the code in your link has `visibility: hidden` set but also sets it to `visible` on `hover`. This would also correct the problem, but I don't see any reason to have `visibility` at all on this.

Also, in your particular example, you need some content in the menu `<li>`s to actually see that it's being shown. See the updated snippet below.

```css
a {
  padding: 4px;
}
i.fa {
  color: #8b8b8b;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
ul li ul {
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
  /*visibility: hidden;*/ /* Not needed, since there is already display:none*/
}
ul li ul:hover {
  display: block;
}
ul li ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="color: #676767;"> <a style="color: #676767;" href="#"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i> Share</a>
    <ul class="socialShare">
      <!-- Need some content in the <li>s -->
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://test.gpjbaker.com/brands/gp-j-baker/denbury-collection/"><i class="fa fa-facebook">
        link a
      </i></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://twitter.com/home?status=http://test.gpjbaker.com/brands/gp-j-baker/denbury-collection/"><i class="fa fa-twitter">
        link b
      </i></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://test.gpjbaker.com/brands/gp-j-baker/denbury-collection/&media=&description="><i class="fa fa-pinterest">
        link c
      </i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```